# Не получается настроить эмулятор андроид устройства

Tags: java, android

Друзья, помогите решить проблему, не могу настроить эмулятор андроид устройства  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проц.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно визуализацию нужно активировать в биосе

Comment: Matty, в биосе нет такой возможности(

Comment: 1) сорри за опечатку - виртуализация, конечно 2) посмотрите еще раз. Настройки для AMD обычно расположены в меню Chipset или Processor, но иногда могут быть спрятаны в других меню, например, Security Settings. В AMD часто обозначается аббревиатурой SVM (Secure Virtual Machines)

Comment: Не мучайтесь, возьмите любой другой андроид эмулятор http://android-emulator.net. Там для каждого есть инструкция по установке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не принципиален способ, попробуйте воспользоваться [другим инструментом](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) для эмуляции приложений, а именно `Genymotion`.

Comment: TimurVI, спасибо огромное, именно Genymotion  получилось поставить и настроить!

Answer (score 1):

У Вас процессор *AMD Athlon X2 QL-62*. Технологию *VT-x* поддерживают только процессоры фирмы *Intel*, а а фирменная технология *AMD* *SVM* в данном процессоре отсутствует. (http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%20X2%20QL-62%20-%20AMQL62DAM22GG.html)

Иными словами, Ваш процессор физически не поддерживает необходимые для эмулятора технологии.

Comment: kff, спасибо за ответ, теперь всё стало ясно.